# Bloquear Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

¿Como puedo bloquear Internet Explorer en mi pagina? Necesito evitar que usen mi sitio web con Internet Explorer 9 o menor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar este código javascript con jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 9){
    $('body').html('<span> Este sitio no soporta IE version < 9.</span>');
}
```

Complementando la respuesta:

Puedes usar **Comentarios condicionales** también, que solo funcionan en **Internet Explorer**, pero te sirven para dar instrucciones adicionales a tus usuarios o cargar librerías (javascript) basado en la version de IE:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
De acuerdo al comentario condicional este es IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
De acuerdo al comentario condicional este es IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
De acuerdo al comentario condicional este es IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Puedes checar información adicional [aqui](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Pero esta respuesta supone el uso de jQuery, que dependiendo de la versión de IE puede no soportar completamente.

Comment: Hola, ya realice algunas pruebas en 6, 7, 8 y 9 y funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que realizamos en algunas intranets/websites es redireccionar a una página que despliega el mensaje "No soportado en Internet Explorer".

El script es muy sencillo (tuve que editar el método para validar IE ver 9 o menor, ya que es algo diferente, pero ahora este método funciona con todos).

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript">
    <!--

    function getIEVersion() {
       var match = navigator.userAgent.match(/(?:MSIE |Trident\/.*; rv:)(\d+)/);
       return match ? parseInt(match[1]) : undefined;
   }


   if(getIEVersion() != undefined){
       if (getIEVersion() <= 9) {
            document.location = "http://www.puisormobile.com/no_ie.html"; //Es IE <= 9, REDIRECCIONA A PAGINA QUE SUGIERE USAR UNA MAYOR VERSIÓN!
       }else{ 
               document.location = "http://www.puisormobile.com/default.html"; // OK, Es IE > 9!
       } 
   }else{
               document.location = "http://www.puisormobile.com/default.html";  // OK, No es IE!
   }    
    // -->
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Con esto sería suficiente para IE < 10: var isIElt10 = document.all && !window.atob && !window.opera;

Answer (score 3):

Una forma mas compacta y sin usar ninguna librería, ni siquiera JavaScript y que al menos funciona a partir de IE6. Tiene la ventaja de funcionar a pesar de que el usuario tenga deshabilitado JavaScript.

Coloca esto dentro del elemento `<head>` de tu pagina:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/ruta/a/actualiza_tu_navegador.html"></meta>
<![endif]-->
```

Explicación:

- `<!--[if lt IE 10]> .. <![endif]-->` Si es internet explorer version menor que 10 (9 o menor)
- `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` dirigirse a
- `content="0;url=pagina.html"` en 0 segundos, ruta: `pagina.html`
- `></meta>` La versiones viejas de IE no soportan la sintaxis `<meta />`, se debe utilizar la sintaxis `<meta></meta>`

Por ultimo, crea una pagina estática llamada `actualiza_tu_navegador.html`, con el mensaje que deseas y por cierto podrías incluirle algunos vínculos para descargar los navegadores que soportas.

Si quieres bloquear todas las versiones de Internet Explorer cambia por `<!--[if IE]>`

Nota: En otros navegadores que no sean IE esto es interpretado como un comentario ya que todo el bloque comienza con `<!--` y finaliza con `-->`. Por ello no tiene ningún efecto.

Comment: Hola. Coloque esto en mi Codigo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/ruta/a/actualiza_tu_navegador.html"></meta>
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">

Pero aun asi me abre la pagina con Internet Explorer 11. ¿Porque?

Answer (score 2):

Realiza una redirección a una pagina en particular que diga algo como: Para utilizar el presente sitio web, te recomendamos utilizar una versión superior de IE u otro navegador actualizado.

Para responder y evitar re-inventar la rueda, vamos a hacer uso de Modernizr
https://modernizr.com/docs

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

            if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                return data[i].identity;
            }
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index === -1) {
            return;
        }

        var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
        if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
            return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
        } else {
            return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
        }
    },

    dataBrowser: [
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Edge", identity: "MS Edge"},
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"},  
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "OPR", identity: "Opera"},  

        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"}, 
        {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"}       
    ]
};

BrowserDetect.init();
document.write("You are using <b>" + BrowserDetect.browser + "</b> with version <b>" + BrowserDetect.version + "</b>");
```

Finalmente, revisamos las siguientes variables y de acuerdo a ello, la redirección antes mencionada

```
BrowserDetect.browser == 'Explorer';
BrowserDetect.version <= 9;
```

Créditos de la respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13480430/3613462

Comment: No estoy usando modernizr. Saludos

Comment: var isIElt10 = document.all && !window.atob && !window.opera; para IE<=9. Pero si se desea que nuestra página se vea casi en todos las versiones de los navegadores sin mucho esfuerzo, y me refiero a programar con ECMAScript 5, usa [WhatCanIuse](https://github.com/Webnewbies/SisePuede#recomendaciones)